# adding a single pole light switch in same box that has 3-way switch

Tags: switch, light

I have a 15 AMP circuit powering a 3-way **switch [A]** - 14/3 - 3-way **switch [B]** to 14/2 to 6 recessed lights in kitchen.  The power comes into the Switch[A]. I want to add a single pole switch in location **switch[B]** to run a hanging light pendant. Can I get power from the 3-way Switch [B] and hookup the new pendant light or do I need to run new power for the pendant light?
If I need to run new power can I run 14/2 wire to **switch box [B]** from a 12/2 box in basement that is on a 15AMP circuit?

---

The 12/2 wire I ran in the basement for lights and 2 outlets when I first moved into the house but they are on a 15 amp circuit.  If I run power from one on the basement outlets 12/2 to the **switch[B]** 12/2 and then run from single pole switch 14/2 to pendant light .. would be OK?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I get power from the 3-way Switch [B]

No.  Forget the idea that you can tap power **from a switch**.  Delete that idea from your brain, it wastes a lot of time.

Every once in a blue moon you get lucky, e.g. Switch [A] might have both always-hot and neutral present.  Post-2011 "switch loops" are required to bring alway-hot and neutral to the switch (take note!!) so you can usually tap there. **But it's not the way to bet.**

> If I run power from one on the basement outlets 12/2 to the switch[B] 12/2 and then run from single pole switch 14/2 to pendant light .. would be OK?

Yes, that's fine.

Note that on 15A circuits, #12 wire is perfectly legit.  I consider it wise for someone who isn't a builder or pro electrician, because the "#14 is cheaper" theory only works if you buy it by the mile.  Go price spools at Home Depot and see for yourself: having to buy two separate spools (a #14 and a #12) is more costly than a larger spool of #12.

Some people will fuss that #12 is harder to work with, but I ask them if they pigtail and use metal boxes and self-grounding receptacles.  Because if they don't, they are wrestling three to five #14 wires, and that is much worse than two #12.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run new power. The black and red wires of the 14/3 should be the travelers and the white wire should be neutral.

14/2 on a 15A circuit is fine.  The 12/2 wire on that circuit bothers me, but that's just me being unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a bit confusing to someone working on the circuit in the future, however #12 on a 15 amp breaker is ok.

The 14/2 from the basement box to the new switch is fine since everything is on a 15 amp breaker.

Comment: Thanks for information